# WP Query, Getting Template

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a query to return 3 particular posts however at the moment they just appear with the three titles in a list as per the query on WP Codex.

I need them to show as per the blog section but am unsure as to where and how to call the template in. This is my code:

```
<?php

// The Query
$include_ids = array( '114', '115', '116' );
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'post__in' => $include_ids ) );

// The Loop
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}

?>
```

Can anyone help me with this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the code to actually include the template you need. The details depend a bit on the theme, but is probably going to be something like:

```
<?php if ( $query->have_posts() )  : ?>
    <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : ?>
        <?php $query->the_post(); ?>
        <?php get_template_part('content', get_post_format()); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Brilliant this worked perfectly thanks! I have another issue which is the theme the client has chosen has a javascript homepage where it pulls each page and it's content in on a horizontal slider. I can get the content of the query to show on the static version of the page but not on the javascript version. http://www.markcv.co.uk Any ideas?

Comment: That theme causes a lot of Javascript files to load. These are probably what is implementing the horizontal slider. If you want to duplicate that you'll probably want to look at the code for that if you have it.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress templates use different template files for different parts of you site. Code that is in `single.php` will be run when you open a single post in the browser. Code in `category.php` will run when you open a category page.

It's not quite clear what you mean by "as per the blog section". If you still need more information, clarify your question and I will update my answer to let you know how to do it.